# F# tail recursion stack overflows when not run locally

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I am having problems running the below recursive function on our development web server. It causes a stack overflow. It runs fine locally when in debugging mode. Here are things I have tried:

1. Made sure 'Generate tail calls' is enabled under build options.
2. I ran the disassembler and followed the instructions here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx and it does not *appear* to be using tail recursion.
3. I've tried rewriting it without using recursion but my F# skills are not the best.

So my questions would be:

1. Is this function going to be able to use tail end recursions?
2. Why would it work locally in debugging mode through VS but not on the dev web server?

Thanks!

```
let rec SimulationLoop (rowNum : int) (h : double) (time : double) (v : double) (s : double) (p : double) (newV' : double) (newS' : double) (newP' : double) (designParameters : DesignParameters) (inputs : ISimulationInputProvider) = seq {
    //let timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
    let finalTime = (6.0 * inputs.ShockAbsorber.Stroke / designParameters.VelocityAfterImpact)    
    let startH = StartH h time finalTime

    let slopes = Slopes v s p newV' newS' newP' startH designParameters inputs
    let vSlope, sSlope, pSlope = slopes
    let betaList = [ for j in 0 .. 5 -> beta.[j].[4] ]
    let newV' = CalcPrime v startH vSlope betaList
    let newS' = CalcPrime s startH sSlope betaList
    let newP' = CalcPrime p startH pSlope betaList

    let delta = Delta h slopes
    let tau = Tau v s p

    let rowResult, rowNum, time, newV, newS, newP = if delta < tau then RecordResults rowNum time startH v s p slopes designParameters inputs else None, (rowNum + 1), time, v, s, p
    let loop = newS < inputs.ShockAbsorber.Stroke - 0.01 && newV >= 0.0 && rowNum <= 8000 && (time < finalTime && time + h > time)
    let stepLength = StrokeStepLength inputs.ShockAbsorber.Stroke designParameters.HoleSize
    let endH = EndH delta startH tau stepLength newV

    //timer.Stop()
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Row: " + rowNum.ToString() + " = " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString())
    match (rowResult, loop) with
        | Row(r), true ->
            yield r
            yield! SimulationLoop rowNum endH time newV newS newP newV' newS' newP' designParameters inputs
        | Row(r), false ->
            yield r
        | None, true ->
            yield! SimulationLoop rowNum endH time newV newS newP newV' newS' newP' designParameters inputs
        | None, false -> ()
}
```

Comment: Since I am in a sequence expression, I believe it has to be yield.

Comment: Indeed, it cannot be `return!`.

Comment: Have you tried implementing this using Seq.unfold ?

Comment: Tail recursion will fail on x64 and .NET 2 with so many parameters. Use .NET 4 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewriting it without recursion. This is not the most elegant solution but it works:

```
let SimulationLoop (rowNum : int) (h : double) (time : double) (v : double) (s : double) (p : double) (newV' : double) (newS' : double) (newP' : double) (designParameters : DesignParameters) (inputs : ISimulationInputProvider) = 
    let mutable mKeepLooping = true
    let mutable mRowNum = 1
    let mutable mEndH = h
    let mutable mTime = time
    let mutable mNewV = v
    let mutable mNewS = s
    let mutable mNewP = p
    let mutable mNewV' = newV'
    let mutable mNewS' = newS'
    let mutable mNewP' = newP'

    let theList = new List<SimulationRow>()

    while mKeepLooping do
        let finalTime = (6.0 * inputs.ShockAbsorber.Stroke / designParameters.VelocityAfterImpact)
        let startH = StartH mEndH mTime finalTime

        let slopes = Slopes mNewV mNewS mNewP mNewV' mNewS' mNewP' startH designParameters inputs
        let vSlope, sSlope, pSlope = slopes
        let betaList = [ for j in 0 .. 5 -> beta.[j].[4] ]
        let mNewV' = CalcPrime v startH vSlope betaList
        let mNewS' = CalcPrime s startH sSlope betaList
        let mNewP' = CalcPrime p startH pSlope betaList

        let delta = Delta mEndH slopes
        let tau = Tau mNewV mNewS mNewP

        let rowResult, rowNum, time, newV, newS, newP = if delta < tau then RecordResults mRowNum mTime startH mNewV mNewS mNewP slopes designParameters inputs else None, (mRowNum + 1), mTime, mNewV, mNewS, mNewP
        mRowNum <- rowNum
        mTime <- time
        mNewV <- newV
        mNewS <- newS
        mNewP <- newP
        let loop = newS < inputs.ShockAbsorber.Stroke - 0.01 && newV >= 0.0 && rowNum <= 8000 && (time < finalTime && time + h > time)
        mKeepLooping <- loop
        let stepLength = StrokeStepLength inputs.ShockAbsorber.Stroke designParameters.HoleSize
        mEndH <- EndH delta startH tau stepLength newV

        match rowResult with
        | Row(r) ->
            theList.Add(r)
        | _ -> ()

    theList
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the body of your function is a sequence expression, the compiler doesn't use tail recursion.  However, merely calling `SimulationLoop` should definitely not cause a stack overflow since it should just generate the sequence without evaluating its contents.  Furthermore, given the nature of your code, I would expect the state machine that the compiler generates for stepping through the sequence to run without overflowing the stack as well.

How are you using the result of calling `SimulationLoop` when you see the error?  What are the platforms for the local and web machines (e.g. are they both 32-bit)?  If you trim down your example (e.g. by removing the calls to `CalcPrime`, `RecordResults`, etc.) do you see the same behavior?

Comment: Both machines are 64 bit. I have tried setting the row count limit to a much lower number, 800 (see the let loop declaration), and it DOES work in that case. However, I need it to be higher than that (8000). So I am fairly confident it has to do with the number of times SimulationLoop is called.

Comment: As aside, I have tried it on other developer's machines running through Visual Studio debugger and it runs successfully. I have tried it on two development web server (both Windows Server 2008 64bit) and they both stack overflow.

Comment: Outside chance: Does the deployment machine have the same version of FSharp.Core as the development machine?